# Decrypt array to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, url

I currently have an array that looks like this:

```
["screen", "left_side", "left_side", "right_side", "left_side", "right_side", "left_side", "right_side"]
```

I now want to encrypt this somehow so I can use it as a URL, like: `http://www.site.com/app.html?array=...` this is because I want to allow users to share their arrays.

Is there any way to encrypt an array to it's usable in a URL string and decrypt it later on?

Comment: "Encrypt"? I think you mean "encode".

Comment: @nnnnnn I guess it depends on how you look at it, I want to safely share an array without making the string too long.

Comment: And your words can only be left_side, right_side and screen?

Comment: @xanatos There are some other words, but in theory they're all fixed yes, so I could basically convert them to fixed numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `atob` and `btoa` functions.

```
myArray = ["screen", "left_side", "left_side", "right_side", "left_side", "right_side", "left_side", "right_side"]
btoa(JSON.stringify(myArray)) // "WyJzY3JlZW4iLCJsZWZ0X3NpZGUiLCJsZWZ0X3NpZGUiLCJyaWdodF9zaWRlIiwibGVmdF9zaWRlIiwicmlnaHRfc2lkZSIsImxlZnRfc2lkZSIsInJpZ2h0X3NpZGUiXQ=="
```

You can then convert it back into the orignal array

```
array = JSON.parse(atob(str))
```

---

If you include [LZString](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string/) (as mentioned in the comments), you can get shorter strings.

```
var str = btoa(JSON.stringify(myArray)); // 132 characters
var str = LZString.compressToBase64(JSON.stringify(myArray)); // 72 characters
var str = LZString.compressToBase64(myArray.toString()); // 64 characters
```

To uncompress,

```
array = JSON.parse(LZString.decompressFromBase64(str));
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HMP6T/)

Comment: I would add compression to this solution. See `compressToBase64` in  http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html

Comment: Thanks @Paul.  I added examples of that.  You can get that array compressed to half the size using it.

Comment: I've been seeing about 5:1 compression using `LZString.compressToUTF16` to store tabular data in `localStorage` with a library I've been working on [html5csv.js](https://github.com/DrPaulBrewer/html5csv)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you...

```
<script>

var uri='http://www.site.com/app.html?["screen", "left_side", "left_side", "right_side", "left_side", "right_side", "left_side", "right_side"]';
var uri_encode=encodeURIComponent(uri);
document.write(uri_encode);
document.write("<br>");
document.write(decodeURIComponent(uri_encode));

</script>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qKfB/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var a = ["screen", "left_side", "left_side", "right_side", "left_side", 
"right_side", "left_side", "right_side"];

var stringa = a.toString;
var encodeda = encodeURI(stringa);
```

Then use it like this

```
var site = "http://www.site.com/app.html?array=" + a;
```